Fitting Hypergeometric distribution requires non-integer arguments?
I have a vector (length s) of observations, x are class "0" and s-x are class "1" and are drawn from a population of size N. Hence, they follow the hypergeometric distribution:
$$H(x| p,s,N) = \frac{ {pN \choose x}  {N-pN \choose s-x} }{ {N \choose s} }$$
I subsample this vector (using $j$ jackknife intervals) to obtain a histogram ($O$) of proportions, with bins $x \in [0, js]$ versus frequency. The size of the population $N$ and the proportion $p$ are unknown and I need to infer them from the observations.
To solve this, I want to fit a hypergeometric distribution the histogram ($O$) using minimum least squares. I am planning on using the Newton-Raphson (NR) method to find the values of $p$ and $N$ that minimize $L = \sum_x (O-H)^2$.
My reasoning is that I need to employ the binomial coefficients with non-integer arguments to numerically calculate the derivatives of $L$ using finite-differences, but I am finding that this leads to negative values for $H$.
Please, I need some feedback. Is this method correct, or how should I infer the values of $N$ and $p$? I am working on top of somebody else's work, so I don't have the option of changing the method drastically (i.e., I can't use Bayesian inference).

The function you're optimising has support that is both discrete and bounded. It might occasionally be temporarily advantageous to ignore the discreteness  (don't take that too far though) but I doubt there's ever any advantage in ignoring the bounds

If you have one or can make one, it might not hurt to post a very small example set that would cause you problems that people can use in responses

Note to begin with that $N$ must be at least $s$. Would this happen to be some kind of mark-and-recapture (capture/recapture) problem?

It's not clear to me how the jackknife will add any information that's not already in $s$ and $x$.

Are the number of "1"s in the population known? Or the number of "0"s? Without this information I suspect you're just going to tend to end up at $\hat{N}=s$ and $\hat{p} = x/\hat{N}$ or something very near to it.

I have convinced myself that this is true. Thank you Glen.

I was looking for several more pieces of information to be able to provide an answer or additional help.
